# Search in JFace TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse

In my plugin i am displaying data in a tree using JFace TreeViewer. The Tree by default is not expanded and only on click of the + it is expanded to levels. However i need to perform a search(text entered by the user) on the entire items of the Tree not just the displayed ones. I understand all the child level items are loaded lazily only after the + is clicked. Is there a way to retieve all the items of the tree and not just the displayed ones.?

Answer (score 2):

Search in a tree is typically implemented using FilteredTree class, which gives you a tree with a textbox above it to place your query into. The FilteredTree class then manages the filtering action. You can see it in action in the preferences dialog.

Even if this doesn't quite fit your requirements, you can referenced FilteredTree source to help you implement your own search facility.

Comment: Thank You. I will look into FilteredTree. But i assume FilteredTree would hide all the remaning elements which do not match the search. maybe tweaking the FilteredTree and having an own implementation of it could help my search

Comment: Right. Filtered tree removes items that do not match your filter/query, which is a pretty good way to show you what you are searching for in a large tree. Play around with it in the preferences dialog to get the feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void searchTree(String searchtext) {

    viewer.collapseAll();
    final int itemCount = viewer.getTree().getItemCount();
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemCount; itemIndex++) {
        TreeItem item = viewer.getTree().getItem(itemIndex);
        if (item.getData().toString().toUpperCase().contains(searchtext.toUpperCase())) {

            viewer.expandToLevel(item.getData(), TreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
            for (int i = 0; i < item.getItems().length; i++) {
                if (item.getItem(i).getData().toString().toUpperCase().contains(searchtext.toUpperCase())) {
                    item.getItem(i).setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 204, 255, 153));
                }

            }
        } else {
            item.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0));
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem